# rusty tennis net posts

Tags: outdoor

The winding handles of our tennis posts are completely rusted and wont turn. Is there any way to save them and be able to actually use them and hang a new net? we tried to tie the net to the posts but the whole thing sags in the middle and wont stay tight.

Comment: You can try spraying the inside of the mechanism with some penetrating oil and letting it sit for a while and then trying again. This may be enough to loosen up the gears inside of it so you can wind it up.

Answer (score 2):

Probably just replacing the winding mechanism makes the most sense.

If penetrating oil fails and you want to try a more extensive rust removal approach, either soak them in a citric acid solution or try electrolytic rust removal (washing soda, water and low-voltage DC electric current.)